# How to detect if there is a child dialog opened C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Is there any way that we can detect if a child Dialog is opened ? 
I tried googling there  is not any good article
There should be a very simple solution to this. 
Can anyone tell me how to do this ? 
Is there any method or property in .Net Framework that I can call to get a boolean value somehow whether there is a Modal dialog is opened over my current window ?

Comment: Please check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409945/can-a-form-tell-if-there-are-any-modal-windows-open

Comment: Dont know if this helps, but you can try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does your child form opened inside the current form, or it is detach from it ? (Is the form location is limited to the area of the form)

Comment: @Orel , It's opened with  new Form1().ShowDialog(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you want to check if the current Form owns any child modal Forms?

simply use the **OwnedForms** Property

```
this.OwnedForms.Any() //should return True if it owns any forms.
```